# Не работает RoutedEvent="KeyUp" при нажатии на любую клавишу

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Добрый день.

Есть в проекте медиаэлемент который загружает видео. Через 4 секунды после загрузки запускается анимация плавного появления картинки. Я хочу чтоб при нажатии на любую кнопку на клавиатуре анимация завершалась и удалялась.  Но ни RoutedEvent="KeyUp", ни RoutedEvent="KeyboardKeyUp" не работает для запуска тригера удаления анимации. Но если использовать RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" то триггер успешно запускается. А мне надо запуск от нажатия кнопки на клавиатуре. Не могу никак понять как это сделать.

```
        <Grid x:Name="main">
        <TabControl BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
            <TabItem Header="Item1" >
                <TabItem.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger SourceName="intro" RoutedEvent="MediaElement.MediaOpened">
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="intro_trigger">
                            <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:4" >
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="coa" Duration="0:0:5"></DoubleAnimation>                              
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="KeyUp" >
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <SkipStoryboardToFill BeginStoryboardName="intro_trigger" />
                            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="intro_trigger" />
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </TabItem.Triggers>
                <Grid Background="Black" >
                    <MediaElement x:Name="intro" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="intro.avi" LoadedBehavior="play" MediaEnded="Intro_End" Stretch="Uniform" />                  
                    <Image x:Name="coa" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Resources/ipsa.png" Opacity="0" Width="180" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Item2">
                <Grid Background="Black">                        
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>    
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте отлавливать непосредственно в коде это событие и уже там взаимодействовать с ним.